# Single sign on with OpenId Connect across different flows

Tags: single-sign-on, openid-connect

Two different websites authenticate with a local OpenId Connect provider using different flows:

- Website A. Standard implicit flow
- Website B. Server uses user credential password flow with user provided username/password

I want to achieve single sign in the two sites, that is, after user authenticates in Website A she is automatically authenticated when visiting Website B and vice versa.

What technique can I use to get this functionality?

[EDIT to explain reasons]

I should explain the reasons for this case:

The main idea was to have a local authorization server (OpenId Connect) handling with all authentication related tasks.

However, for the main site, the major requirement for a good user experience is to provide login as a seamless inpage operation, without redirections nor new windows. So the authentication is performed as an AJAX call: the browser sends the username/password to the website server which requests authentication to the authorization server using user credentials password flow.

Other untrusted websites should authenticate with the authorization server using the standard implicit flow.

So the question can be reformulated as: how can I authenticate users in a website with its own login form using an OpenId Connect server maintaining single sign on capabilities.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: that's impossible in the described configuration because website B asks for user credentials without checking if an SSO session already exists at the Provider (since that's how the user credential password flow works).

But are you really sure that website B uses a Resource Owner Password Credential flow? That flow is not explicitly defined in OpenID Connect and that is exactly because of the issue you're facing: it adds no security value over LDAP or HTTP Basic flows since the Relying Party gets to see the users' password at the Provider. Because of that there's virtually no OpenID Connect Provider deployment or implementation that would support it.

Solution: make both website A and B use the Basic Client Profile, which is preferred over the Implicit Client Profile because of the exposure of tokens in URLs/redirects/logs/headers in the latter.